# UILabel fade-in fade-out question

Tags: iphone, animation, uilabel, fade

I got the following code inside an NSTimer selector:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[infoLbl setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[infoLbl setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So I want to implement a simple fade-in/fade-out loop upon a UILabel (infoLbl).

Well, with this code I get only the fade-in step, since the UILabel suddenly disappear, then fades-in.

Some suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[infoLbl setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

//This delegate is called after the completion of Animation.
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
  [infoLbl setAlpha:1];
  [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Insetad of this, if you are using NStimer Selecor then y dont u tryout changing color of the uilabel text? like:

```
-(void)timerSelector
{
    if([textLabel textColor] == [UIColor blackColor])
    {
        [textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];   
    }
    else
    {
        [textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];  
    }
}
```

Above method will enable you to fade in/out in a loop pretty easily.

Comment: YES! Thanks! (I used the first one sample).

Answer (score 0):

Fade in first, setting an `animationDidStopSelector:` and inside the selector (see documentation for more information), tell it to fade out.

Comment: Ok I did that:
-(void)fadeLoop {
 [self fadeIn];
}
-(void)fadeIn {
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
 [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(fadeOut:finished:context:)];  [infoLbl setAlpha:1.0];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)fadeOut:(NSString*)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void*)context  {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    infoLbl.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

now it doesn't fade-in nor fade-out

Comment: Set the animationDelegate of the first animation to self.